# Silverlight 4 / telerik RadControl, missing assembly question

Tags: silverlight, telerik-grid

Error. The type or namespace name 'GridViewExpressionColumn' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Hello all,

I've inherited a VisualStudio 2010, Silverlight 4 project with a custom RadControl from Telerik. The project runs fine on the server, but I would like to make some changes locally. When I copied the project folder over to my c drive, the application cannot compile (build errors). After cleaning the solution, I still keep running into CLS-compliant issues, and most notably, the error listed above. I'm not sure what the problem is, since I've never worked with Telerik or third party RadControls. Any help would be appriciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to contact your office software guru and get a licensed copy of Telerik RadControls to install on your local development machine.

To get you compiling, for now, you can use the demo version available at http://www.telerik.com/support/demos/developer-tools-demos.aspx - any solutions compiled from this will show a big "DEMO" banner accross the control for a few seconds.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What if my machine already has Telerik RadControls installed?

Comment: There are two ways to add the references to your project - you can either add them manually (Add Reference, then browse to the Telerik folder and do all that) or you can use the handy Telerik install plugin for Visual Studio.

Try right clicking on the silverlignt project and see if you have an option for "Rad Controls For Silverlight" and go from there...